# Python - ignore exception for log

Tags: python, exception, logging, odoo

I have this method:

```
def get_sftp_connection(self, log_error=True):
    self.ensure_one()
    login = self.login_id
    LogCustom = self.env['log.custom']
    try:
        transport = Transport((login.host, login.port))
        transport.connect(username=login.user, password=login.passwd)
        sftp = SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)            
    except socket.gaierror:
        msg = _("Name or service '%s' not known") % (login.host)
        if log_error:
            LogCustom.log_error_event(operation='read', ref=self._get_rec_description(), name=msg)
        raise ValidationError(msg)
    return sftp
```

And I want to create log record in database if exception occurs. But python/psycopg2 seems to rollback any changes, because of exception. When I check if log was created before `raise` occured. And it is, but after raise everything is rollbacked.

Is it possible to `raise` and at the same time create log in database? Like wrapping log creation in some different transaction or something (so it would avoid rollback)

Comment: Maybe you could save the logs in a file and after the rollback you could populate the files to the database

Comment: @ChesuCR thats sounds a bit messy. And the thing is, logging has other related functionality which needs to happens just after creating this log. If I would save logs in a file, then I would need run some kind of cron job to check those files periodically.

Comment: You can force the commit in the database with this instruction: `self.env.cr.commit()`, but it's not recommendable. Or maybe you can use another thread to create another transaction and avoid the rollback? It's only an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chosen to skip raise, if logging option is checked, so then I can create logs in database. Though I had to adjust the code to expect that `None` can be returned from this method.

This is actually a work around. If there is better full proof/safe solution, please post it as an answer.

```
def get_sftp_connection(self, log_error=True):
    self.ensure_one()
    login = self.login_id
    LogCustom = self.env['log.custom']
    ref = self._get_rec_description()
    try:
        transport = Transport((login.host, login.port))
        transport.connect(username=login.user, password=login.passwd)
        sftp = SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)            
    except socket.gaierror:
        msg = _("Name or service '%s' not known") % (login.host)
        if log_error:
            LogCustom.log_warning_event(operation='read', ref=ref, name=msg)
            return None
        else:
            raise ValidationError(msg)
    return sftp
```